# Is the first ECC of Reed-Solomon always the same as xor?

Tags: java, zxing, reed-solomon

I am working with reed-solomon at the moment. As far, as I understand, the first error correction code is always the same as xor'ing the data words, because the first row of the vandermonde matrix is always 1 and the addition of elements in a galois field is equivalent to xor.

Now I tried to get some code words using the Zxing 3.3.0 implementation of ReedSolomonEncoder. See the following listing in Java:

```java
ReedSolomonEncoder rs = new ReedSolomonEncoder(GenericGF.QR_CODE_FIELD_256);

int[] codeword = {72,87,0,0};

rs.encode(codeword, 2);
System.out.println("Ecc for " + codeword[0] + " and " + codeword[1]);
System.out.println("XOR: " + (72^87));
System.out.println("RS #1: " + codeword[2]); // Shouldn't this be 31 too?
System.out.println("RS #2: " + codeword[3]);
```

Which gives the following output:

```
Ecc for 72 and 87
XOR: 31
RS #1: 28
RS #2: 3
```

There are two possibilities:

1. I have a misconception of Reed-Solomon
2. I am using the implementation in a wrong way (as the javadoc is poorly written)

Or this is a bug, which I somehow do not believe.

Comment: I wonder if it's a coincidence that 28 + 3 = 31?

Comment: @AdrianPetrescu I checked this. It seems, that XOR = RS#1 (xor) RS#2 always applies.

Comment: Okay, cool! Then the next thing I would check is if RS#1 always contains the high-order byte half of the sum, and RS#2 always contains the low-order byte half of the sum, the way it is in this example. If so, I think that's your answer - you're correct, it's just that ZXing is storing each byte separately in the output array.

Comment: But I want to have two correction words. The first one should be 31, the second should be 2*87 + 72 (using the operators of GF(256)) = 164 + 72 = 236 (if i did the math right)

Comment: @Obererpel - I updated my answer to include examples of syndrome generation via long division like method. Link to wiki article which explains [syndrome generation via summation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reed%E2%80%93Solomon_error_correction#Syndrome_decoding) for Sj, except for this case `j` goes from 0 to n-k-1, so the two syndromes are S0 and S1, where S0 is the xor of the elements in the decoded message.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's the first syndrome that is the exclusive or of the encoded message, and only if the generator polynomial is of the form (x+1) (x+α) (x+α^2) ... . In this case, the "first consecutive root" is 1. For other implementations, the "first consecutive root" is α, and the generator polynomial is (x+α) (x+α^2) (x+α^3) ... . There are other variations for generator polynomial choice, such as (x+a^127)(x+a^128) in GF(256) for a self reciprocal polynomial, 1x^2 + ??x + 1.

GF(256) in this case is based on the 9 bit polynomial x^8+x^4+x^3+x^2+1 or hex 11d . α is the primitive, and in this case α = x+0 == hex 02.

The generator polynomial is (1x + 1) (1x + 2) = 1x^2 + 3x + 2. The encode process can be visualized as long division, as shown below in hex. The message is multiplied by x^2 (padded with two zeroes) to leave room for the two parity bytes:

```
               48 8f
        ------------
1  3  2 |48 57 00 00
         48 d8 90
         --------
            8f 90 00
            8f 8c 03
            --------
               1c 03   remainder
```

The remainder is subtracted from the padded message, but both add and subtract are exclusive or for GF(256), so the encoded messages becomes

```
48 57 1c 03
```

which matches the result you're getting (hex 1c = decimal 28).

When decoding, in this case, syndrome[0] is the xor of all the bytes in the message. The syndromes can also be visualized as long division (no padding is used for syndrome calculation):

```
        syndrome 0:                 syndrome 1:

          48 09 03                    48 c7 8f
      ------------                ------------
 1  1 |48 57 1c 03           1  2 |48 57 1c 03
       48 48                       48 90
       -----                       -----
          1f 1c                       c7 1c
          1f 1f                       c7 93
          -----                       -----
             03 03                       8f 03
             03 03                       8f 03
             -----                       -----
                00                          00
```

Create a error value of 01 by changing 57 to 56:

```
          48 1e 02                    48 c6 8d
      ------------                ------------
 1  1 |48 56 1c 03           1  2 |48 56 1c 03
       48 48                       48 90
       -----                       -----
          1e 1c                       c6 1c
          1e 1e                       c6 91
          -----                       -----
             02 03                       8d 03
             02 02                       8d 07
             -----                       -----
                01                          04
```